# Converting ISO8601 Date Format to local time (iOS)

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, utc

So there is a section on web application that users can enter events into and the web service sends those events to the mobile app in the following format:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
```

I'm having issues trying to convert the string into a date so I can get just the time from the event (formatted in the correct timezone as well), So for example here's one that comes over "2015-03-20T20:00:00-07:00", which when I pull the time should be 1PM Pacific Time. But instead I either get 8PM or 3AM (depending on whether I add UTC abbreviation to the date formatter).

Here's what I have so far, I know I'm missing something here & maybe there's another date formatter that needs to be used but so far I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

```
NSString *datePattern = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:datePattern];
NSString *sString = [valueDict valueForKey:@"start_date"];
NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:sString];
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
[timeFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
NSString *timeString = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:startDate];
```

Comment: Thanks @Rob , I guess that's what's causing the confusion because the Web Dev Team that created the process to store the dates in the DB say that this is UTC formatted with an offset, and the web site shows it as 1PM Pacific Time (which is the time the user selected). So if it's converting them incorrectly I'll let them know it's on their side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2015-03-20T20:00:00-07:00` *is* 8pm Pacific Daylight Time.

If you're representing 1pm PDT, that's either

- `2015-03-20T13:00:00-07:00`

or represent that in "Zulu" (i.e. GMT/UTC)

- `2015-03-20T20:00:00Z`

When working with a web service, the latter is the common convention for ISO 8601 dates. Then, when you present it to the user, you present it to them in their local timezone (using a `NSDateFormatter` with its default `timeZone` setting.

---

Note, when using `NSDateFormatter` to prepare ISO 8601 dates, you will want to ensure that you specify a `locale` of `en_US_POSIX` as outlined in [Technical Q&A QA1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html). When designing app for US audience this isn't critical, but it's best practice in case the user is not using a gregorian calendar on their device.